# Can we add multiple style properties in navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I just started up with bootstrap and had this question in mind whether or not can we use multiple style properties in the navbar or not?

For example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #f1d1d1;"> // now here one add text-transformation and other properties?
```

Comment: You can use multiple style properties. It's recommended to use a css class instead of using an inline style.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the inline style properties but it is a good practice to create a custom class so that you can use it later when required. One example based on your code is below:

```css
.bg-color-1 {
  background-color: #f1d1d1;
}

.text-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-color-1 text-uppercase">Test</nav>
```

Comment: So, for this, I have to make a CSS class explicitly? For including these: .bg-color-1 {
  background-color: #f1d1d1;
}

.text-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

Comment: It is a good practice to use that for a neater solution. I have tried using page builders and using inline styles but the design is not consistent throughout the site. I still struggle with it. So I switch to custom CSS to save time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use as many classes as you want in any given element as long as they are separated by a space